# Does the type in this KVC validation method matter?

Tags: iphone, validation, core-data, key-value-coding

For example, in the docs a KVC-style validation method is implemented like this:

```
-(BOOL)validateAge:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError
```

They used id* as the type for ioValue. Since that's not part of the method signature, I wonder if it would hurt to do something like:

```
-(BOOL)validateAge:(NSNumber *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError
```

Is this still fine with KVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not work because they are not the same. `id*` would be closer to `NSNumber**` as the method accepts a pointer to a pointer.  So your method would look like:

```
-(void)validateAge:(NSNumber**)ioValue error:(NSError**)outError
```

But there is **NO** point in doing that. `id` will work perfectly fine for everything that you need to do and if you change it and then adjust that attribute later you can and would introduce a subtle error into your application.

Short answer, yes you can change the input parameter type; but you **really** shouldn't.